# Can't import or use "builder" for RecyclerView view matching with Kakao Cup

Tags: android, android-espresso

Trying to do UI testing with Kakao cup and I'm frustrated on trying to get a matcher working with `RecyclerView`

https://github.com/KakaoCup/Kakao#create-the-klistviewkrecyclerview

This is their example:

```
val recycler = KRecyclerView { builder = { withId(R.id.recycler_view) } }
```

I'm trying to do the same thing:

```
val homeRecyclerView: KRecyclerView = KRecyclerView {
    builder = {
        withId(R.id.home_page_recycler_view)
    }
}
```

But `builder` is highlighted in red and it doesn't want me to import anything. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hover your mouse over `builer` to see what the error is. Then google that error message.

Comment: It just shows unresolved reference. Only offers me to create a variable with it which isn't right. Tried to re-sync and invalidate caches/restart.